# Randomized Black-White Canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, javascript-objects

with the help of the community I managed to get my first project done, now when I tried to create a new version of this, as I thought I had understood it, I struggled again. I've searched throughout the internets js documentations etc. but it simply doesn't do what I expect..

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting all colors for the iData.data object?
From my understanding

```
iData.data[i]=(Math.random() < 0.5)? 255 : 0;
```

declares an object which has a randomized value compared to smaller than 0,5,
if true the value is set to 255, else to 0;

How does it get to the other values, the result seems to be less equally distributed random, but still contains colors I did not expect (not 255|0).

Thanks in Advance.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
function draw() {

var canvas=document.getElementById("resizable");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var iData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height); 

for(var i=0; i<iData.data.length; i++) //or i=+4
{
    iData.data[i]=(Math.random() < 0.5)? 255 : 0;
//    iData.data[i+1]=(Math.random() < 0.5)? 255 : 0;
//    iData.data[i+2]=(Math.random() < 0.5)? 255 : 0;
//    iData.data[i+3]=(Math.random() < 0.5)? 255 : 0;

}
ctx.putImageData(iData,0,0);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this from w3schools but I modified it a bit. Hope it helps!

```
var black = [0, 0, 0, 255];
var white = [255, 255, 255, 255];
var colors = [black, white];

function fillImageData(imgData, rgba) { //fills the image data with one color
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
    imgData.data[i+0] = rgba[0];
    imgData.data[i+1] = rgba[1];
    imgData.data[i+2] = rgba[2];
    imgData.data[i+3] = rgba[3];
    }
    return imgData;
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(100, 100);

var choice = Math.round(Math.random()); //picks 0 or 1 as the index

imgData = fillImageData(imgData, colors[choice]);

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);
```

I have the jsfiddle if youre interested in seeing it in action. http://jsfiddle.net/squat/qxba3pxc/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cameron,

your reply helped me to understand the usage of rgba and now the reaction finally makes sense.

This is my version of what I wanted to create:

function draw() {

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("resizable");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var iData = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var black = 0;
    var white = 255;


    for (var i = 0; i < iData.data.length; i+=4)
    {
        var dec = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? white : black;
        iData.data[i] = dec;
        iData.data[i+1]=dec;
        iData.data[i+2]=dec;
        iData.data[i+3]=white;

    }
    ctx.putImageData(iData, 0, 0);
```

}